# How do I create Cassandra Interpreter for Zeppelin on AWS EMR Spark cluster

Tags: cassandra, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

What should be the values for Interpreter group, Properties and dependency..
Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **existing** Zeppelin's interpreters for spark and cassandra, just enable them in settings: 
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.5.5-incubating/interpreter/cassandra.html

If you are trying to **create** a custom interpreter (I'm sure it's not what you want), just extend `org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter` and implement necessary methods, so you code can be interpreted. Follow the instructions in the documentstion: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/development/writingzeppelininterpreter.html#make-your-own-interpreter